# Can libjpeg-turbo set the color of pixels?

Tags: c++, optimization, imagemagick, jpeg, magick++

I have written a program using Magick++ which generates a JPEG file with each of its pixels set to a random color. It works well, but is a bit slow for my purposes.

I have read that libjpeg-turbo is faster - but from reading through its documentation I can only find functions and examples that read from an existing image file and compress that. Is it possible, using libjpeg-turbo, to set the pixel values of a jpeg programmatically?

Is there any other way I might try to create images more quickly? I'm open to trying different file types if one of them could allow for a faster algorithm. My ultimate goal is to create a CGI program which will display the randomly generated images on a webpage.

This is the code I am using with Magick++:

```
Image babel( Geometry(640, 416), Color(MaxRGB, MaxRGB, MaxRGB, 0));
babel.magick("JPEG");

boost::multiprecision::mpz_int color;
for (unsigned x=0;x<798720;x++) {
color = *pointer % 16;
if (color<10) {where += ('0'+color.convert_to<int>());}
else {where += ('7' + color.convert_to<int>());}
if (x%3==2) {babel.pixelColor((x%1920)/3,x/1920,Color(where)); where="#";}
*pointer = *pointer >> 4;
}
babel.write("rando.jpg");
```

----update-----

As has been pointed out below, Magick++ is not causing the slowness of this program. I'd welcome any advice on optimizing the other aspects of this for loop.

Comment: How fast is your for loop without using Magick++? It looks to me that Magick++ is not the bottleneck.

Comment: I believe you are correct. I replaced the line which set the pixelcolor with the following: `if (x%3==2) {y= (x%1920)/3; y= x/1920;}`, and the total time for the program went from 23 to 22 seconds. So I will need to focus on making the loop more efficient, rather than using a different image library. I'll definitely need to work with smaller images. If anyone has any advice on optimizing that loop I would welcome it. Otherwise, I will abandon this question. Thank you, @Wimmel

Comment: Can you create, say, 4 threads and let each thread generate a quarter of the image?

Comment: @JonathanBasile I think the string operations are slow, it would be better to use a lookup table. And unnecessary divide and mod operations can make it slow. I would suggest to try two for loops, for `x` and `y` separate. But feel free to delete this question.

Comment: What do the images look like, btw?

Comment: Here's an example: http://imgur.com/gallery/0NA67tr/new - nested loops and a lookup table are both excellent suggestions.

Comment: I haven't worked with multithreading before, @MarkSetchell - this seems like an excellent time to learn. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Please feed back any improvements you get through threading - thanks.

Comment: The look up table provided a significant performance boost - from 23 seconds to 8 seconds - but I havent had any success so far with threading. Any program I create which attempts to write to an Image from multiple threads suffers runtime errors such as: `Assertion failed: (image->cache != (Cache) NULL), function GetPixelCacheVirtualMethod, file magick/cache.c, line 2321.
     Assertion failed: (relative->signature == MagickSignature), function InheritException, file magick/exception.c, line 632.
     Abort trap: 6`

Comment: I'm not sure whether something about the ImageMagick libraries prevents them from working with multithreading, or whether it would be possible if I changed my implementation somehow.

Comment: Hey @MarkSetchell - thank you again for the suggestion - I was able to get the final inch of performance I needed from multithreading. Im using 8 threads now and the average run time has gone from 7.5 seconds to just under 4

Comment: That's brilliant news - well done!